# Add layer of a shapefile into ArcGIS map

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-android

I need to develop an Android application that shows a given shapefile within a map. The problem is that shapefile is only visible if I dont use any mapoption at all (in xml file I delete the mapoption field). Shapefile consists some points in the map and are not visible if mapoption is set to any option streets, hybrid.  https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapOptions.MapType.html

```
 try {
       shapefileFeatureTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/test.shp");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File: not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileFeatureTable);
    featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol(
            getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
            SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE.SOLID)));
    if (featureLayer.getSpatialReference()==mMapView.getSpatialReference())
        test.setText("Correct Spatial Reference");
    else
        test.setText("Incorrect Spatial Reference");
    mMapView.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by converting my Shapefile to KML file and then added a KML layer to my map.

I converted the Shapefile to KML online.I am not sure about the link but i think the link to the page is this one https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/
I used dropbox link to use the layer instead of SD card and it works perfectly except that it take some time to load.

```
 mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    KmlLayer kmlLayer = new  KmlLayer("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/yplzwva85tzrabc/test.kml?dl=0");
    mMapView.addLayer(kmlLayer);
```

Comment: Did you convert your Shapefile to KML using ArcMap, or by using another method?  What map did you add your KML layer to, and how?